# When does it matter if random variables are defined on a common probability space?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If I've got two random variables $X$ and $Y$, when does it matter if I think of them both having the same sample space $\Omega$ or not? I sometimes hear phrases like "assuming a common probability space" but I don't have a good idea of where this could matter. Like I know we could have a sequence of RVs $X_1,\dots$ with $X_n\stackrel d\to Y$ and they don't have to be on a common probability space because this just needs the CDFs to behave in a certain way. But why does this matter? What is gained or lost by $X$ and $Y$ sharing $\Omega$ or not?

Comment: How could you make sense of any multivariate characteristic, such as a covariance, when the variables are not defined on the same space?

Comment: @whuber hmm ok so something like $E(XY)=\int_\Omega XY dP$ makes sense but if I have $X$ defined on $\Omega_X$ and $Y$ on $\Omega_Y$, there isn't a way to get something similar? Like integrating over $\Omega_X\times\Omega_Y$ or something? And is this why people comment on convergence in distribution not needing a common probability space? Because that's the unusual situation?

Comment: Right--you can *construct* a bivariate random variable if you need to.  It's therefore simpler to avoid the construction and stipulate--*without any loss of generality*--that $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same space.  I don't understand what you mean by "unusual situation," though, because different results require different concepts of convergence.

Comment: @whuber ok that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to perform algebraic operations on the random variables like add or multiply them, then they have to be on the same probability space. Random variables are nothing but measurable functions from the probability space $\Omega$ to the space of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. When we say $X+Y$ or $X\cdot Y$ or any such operation for that matter, we mean a pointwise operation, i.e. $X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.
You are right that convergence in distribution does not require a common probability space, because the distributions (CDFs) are functions $F:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ and convergence in distributions only implies pointwise convergence of the distributions.

Comment: thank you, that's a very helpful way to look at it